# Videojs can't play m3u8 blob URL

Tags: blob, video.js, m3u8

I am using Videojs version 7.6.6. It will not play a html5 `video` if the `src` is a blob URL. It will load the video time however, but will not play. I get this warning, and then it loads forever:

```
VIDEOJS: WARN: Problem encountered with the current HLS playlist. Trying again since it is the only playlist.
```

This is the way my code runs:

```
<video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-matrix vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls 
preload="none" width="640" height="268" data-setup="{}"></video>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/video-766.min.js"></script>
<script>
fetch("https://server/hls/index.m3u8").then(result => result.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var player = videojs("my_video");
      player.src({ src: blobURL, type: "application/x-mpegURL" });
    }
    );
</script>
```

If I try it without a blob, just a regular URL to the index.m3u8 file, then it works. So this is a problem with the creation of the blob URL I think. This works, the video starts playing:

```
<video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls preload="none">
 <source src="https://server/hls/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
<script>
    var player = videojs('my_video');
</script>
```

I have searched for this issue and found a lot, but none of it helps me. Am I creating the blob wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The object URL that is generated for the blob will start with `file://` protocol if I'm not wrong. Browsers doesn't let you load data with `file://` URL. I ran into a similar problem so I created a simple server on my app which returns the requested file over `https://` .

The reason why your `index.m3u8` is running because it is served over `https` protocol